# spark-streaming-kafka doesn't work with scala-library

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to setup an integration of `kafka_2.11-1.1.0` with `spark-2.2.0.`

According to official docs from here
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html
I've downloaded `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.10-2.2.0.jar` and put it to `SPARK_HOME/jars`.

I've successfully created the stream object

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(
    ssc, 
    '127.0.0.1:2181', 
    'spark', 
    {'test':1}
)
```

but when I run

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I get

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

As I see from `scala-library-2.11.8.jar` that is a part of `spark-2.2.0 jars` - there is only `scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce` does exist.

`scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class` is not there - it was there in early versions.

So what does it mean? This integration doesn't work at all in `spark-2.2.0`?

Please share your successful experience if you have this integration working.

Comment: Sorry all, i found my error - i've downloaded spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.10-2.2.0.jar wich is for scala 2.10
I've just downloaded spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar and the integration works fine.

Comment: Feel free to answer questions below rather than in the comments